# Why won't my Swift-backed Preference Pane load?

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nspreferencepane

I am trying to create a custom System Preferences pane for my app. However, when I try to load it to test, I get this in the Console:

```
Apr 26 17:16:17 computer-name System Preferences[8545]: dlopen_preflight failed with dlopen_preflight(/Users/username/Library/PreferencePanes/App Name.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/App Name): Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAppKit.dylib
      Referenced from: /Users/username/Library/PreferencePanes/App Name.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/App Name
      Reason: image not found for /Users/username/Library/PreferencePanes/App Name.prefPane
```

It seems like the Swift wrapper for AppKit failed to load... something I'm sure I need. **So what happened here and how do I fix it?**